# When should I use System.Windows.Input.Cursors.AppStarting?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-interface, usability

I want to visually tell my users, that they are able to interact with the application while performing some workload in the background without blocking the user interface.

I thought about using the mouse cursor with an arrow and an loading indicator (like a sandglass [image: arrow with loading sandglass cursor] or the spinning circle [image: arrow with loading circle cursor]).

Microsoft therefor offers the `AppStarting` in [`System.Windows.Input.Cursors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.cursors) class, which is described as following:

> Gets the Cursor that appears when an application is starting.

**My Question is:** Is this cursor dedicated to indicate that the application is working as intended? What is the best practice?

Comment: You can change your cursor to wait cursor by Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor, but what do you mean by "Is this cursor dedicated to indicate that the application is working as intended?"

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota The problem is that the users reported that they didn't realize that the application is responding and can be interacted with when using `Cursors.WaitCursor`

Comment: That's exactly why you should *not* change the cursor.

Comment: @mm8 What "exactly" do you mean?

Comment: @WoIIe: Read my answer.

Comment: The AppStarting cursor was very common in Windows NT (*e.g.* Windows NT 3.1). When you launched [File Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-file-manager/9p7vbbbc49rb?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0&activetab=pivot:overviewtab), the cursor would changed to AppStarting. It was a very nice UI touch; that really drove home to me the power of pre-emptive multitasking - where yes something was busy, but your computer was still fully available to you.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out by looking at the remarks in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.cursors.appstarting?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Input_Cursors_AppStarting):

> The AppStarting typically indicates that the system is loading information, but the user interface can handle input.

---

I also found this [windows design guideline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742466(v=vs.85).aspx) by Microsoft about "Mouse and Pointers":

> **Name:** Working in background pointer
>
> **Description:** Used to point, click, press, or select while a task completes in the background.